# Pass Resources Folder path to the command when running a jar

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I have built a jar file without including my resource folder. Because property file need to be edited when running the jar. But I am not aware how to pass the resources folder path along with the jar command. Current command that I use to run the jar is as follows

> java -jar myProject.jar

I also tried below command

```
java -jar myProject.jar -Dconfig=/a/full/path
```

**UPDATE**
As I want to edit my property file **before running the jar file** I don't want to embed resources folder within the jar file. I need the resources folder path to be passed to the command which used to run the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Using the resources system (`MyClass.class.getResource`/`getResourceAsStream` is the right way; commonly written as `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource` or `getClass().getResource` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` which are all subtly wrong) is not correct for 'mutable' files.

If there is a properties file, then look for it in the user's home dir (`Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "myapp.properties")`. If it isn't there, then load the default version of this file, packed into your jar, by reading it with `.getResource`, and write it to that location, then inform the user they can edit it there.

Having a file that you write to from your own process next to your jar is a bad security practice and in general an obsolete application model, going on 20 years now. Directories containing executable code should not be writable except by the user themselves and admin users. An app has absolutely no business writing anything anywhere near executables. If your system even lets you, then your OS / your user settings are misconfigured. Or at the very least, *assuming* (i.e. **forcing**) a user of a computer to run in a mode that means the processes they start can write to the place the executables live - is just bad software.

conclusion: You think you want to write to a properties file that lives next to your jar, but you don't. Instead, write in user.home - that's what it is for.

Comment: I am not writing into my property file. I want to change properties before running my jar based on the environment such as a file path, database name , username etc. therefore I want to pass the resource folder into my command